# keep program in ssh running when network lost

Tags: ssh, server, gnu-screen

I have a problem how to keep my program run in ssh when the laptop(Mac) loses wifi-connection or network. I was running a python program remotely by ssh into a server, and before I run the code I made a new screen by entering 'screen'. And then I ran the program and pressed ctrl+A+D to detach the screen. Everything looked fine and the program continued to work when the laptop was closed( in a place with WIFI). However when I walked outside with my laptop for several minutes and I reopened the laptop it showed 'write fail: broken pipe' and the program stopped. I guess the problem happened because the laptop lost the network connection. Is there any way to fix this problem such that I could bring my laptop anywhere and keep my program run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the `screen` on the remote server after SSHing in so you have a persistent session there, not on your local box.

If you did that, note that you'll still get disconnected if you loose connection but then SSHing in again and re-open the `screen` session to get back to work.

```
local$ ssh remote.server
remote$ screen -ls # list screens
remote$ screen -dr <screen name> # force reconnect to screen session
```

**edit:**

With using `screen` you get a permanent session that you can restore. This sessions will live where you start it. If you want to make sure that you keep running something on the remote server, then first `SSH` and then start the `screen` on the remote.

If you loose connection, then only your `SSH` connection will be terminated and you'll be disconnected from your `screen` session but that won't stop. You can `SSH` in again and reconnect to the `screen` session.

Try this:

```
local$ ssh remote.server
remote$ screen -S date
# screen starts with name 'date'. if it's the first time you start screen on
# this box it might display some welcome message where you need to press enter

remote-screen$ while true; do date; sleep 1; done
# this will show the time every second

# disconnect your network: the ssh connection will be terminated
# open console again and continue

local$ ssh remote.server
remote$ screen -dr date
```

After re-connecting to the `screen` session you should see the dates still going without any pause.

Comment: thanks. So I should first ssh into the server, then open the screen and run the program? The order should not be changed right? And if I get my network connection lost, the program in the sever would stop working. But if I ssh again into the sever, the program would continue to work. Is that what you mean?